# Environment variables: Heroku -> Docker -> Nginx -> React

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, heroku

I have a React app, created with `create-react-app`, running in Nginx, in a Docker container on Heroku. My Docker file looks like this:

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent
RUN npm audit fix
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /etc/nginx/html
CMD sed -i -e 's/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

I want to be able to pass enviroment variables defined in Heroku onto the React app, but I can't find out how and just adding them to the Heroku app and trying to use them in the usual way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Telling Nginx to use `$PORT` (Heroku -> Docker -> Nginx):
Your regex might be off. `'s/$PORT/'"$PORT"'/g'`. I don't know what your nginx.conf looks like but you need to replace the default port number with the new port number. This could be for example: `"s/8080/$PORT/g"` or `'s/8080/'$PORT'/g'` (identical behavior but different syntax `"` and `'`)

Telling your React App to use `$PORT` (Heroku -> Docker -> React):

In your Dockerfile build environment:

```
ENV PORT=$PORT
```

In your javascript code:

```
const port =  process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that bit works. It's any other variable into the Heroku app itself which is the issue.